# Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(\sum_{j=1}^{p}a_j^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\max\{a_1,\ldots,a_p\}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For $a_1,\ldots,a_p$ positive numbers. Show  that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(\sum_{j=1}^{p}a_j^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\max\{a_1,\ldots,a_p\}$.

My attempt was: for $p=1$ i have that $\left(\sum_{j=1}^{p}a_j^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=a_1$ then $\lim a_1=a_1=\max \{a_1\}$. For $p=2$ we have that $\left(\sum_{j=1}^{p}a_j^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=(a_1^n+a_2^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq 2^{\frac{1}{n}}\max\{a_1,a_2\}$ therefore $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(\sum_{j=1}^{2}a_j^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq\max\{a_1,a_2\}$. I guess that the same argument works taking all the numbers $a_j$ but i do not how to prove the equality. The definition have to be, for all $\epsilon>0$ i need to find some $N_{\epsilon}$ integer such that
$$|\left(\sum_{j=1}^{p}a_j^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}-\max\{a_1,\ldots,a_p\}|<\epsilon$$.

I will appreciate any hint please!! Thank you

Comment: Divide the numbers by the max , then the Summation will tend to 1.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate question; but briefly, show that if $M = \max\{a_1, \ldots, a_p\}$, then $M^n \le \sum_{j=1}^p a_j^n \le p \cdot M^n$; then take both sides to the $1/n$ power and apply the squeeze theorem.

Comment: thank you for you hints, Prem and Daniel!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$ \left(\sum_{j=1}^{p}a_j^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\exp \left ( \frac{1}{n}\log \left (\sum_{j=1}^{p}a_j^n  \right )   \right ) $$
we shall evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\log \left (\sum_{j=1}^{p}a_j^n  \right )$. Without loss of generality, suppose that $a_1$ is the largest one among all $a_i$'s, then
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\log \left (\sum_{j  = 1}^{p}a_j^n  \right ) & = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\log \left (a_1^n\sum_{j  = 1}^{p}\left ( \frac{a_j}{a_1}  \right ) ^n  \right )\\
&=\log a_1+\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\log \left (\sum_{j  = 1}^{p}\left ( \frac{a_j}{a_1}  \right ) ^n  \right )
\end{align}$$
Since $\sum_{j  = 1}^{p}\left ( \frac{a_j}{a_1}  \right ) ^n$ is bounded by $p$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\log \left (\sum_{j=1}^{p}a_j^n  \right )=\log a_1$ and hence
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(\sum_{j=1}^{p}a_j^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=a_1$$

Comment: Why is bounded by $p$, sorry i do not get it.

Comment: @weymar andres Every $a_j$ is not larger than $a_1$, hence $\left ( \frac{a_j}{a_1}  \right ) ^n\leqslant 1$ and hence the sum is bounded by $p$.